# Change 'pagingType' option of DataTables (jQuery+Bootstrap4) in smaller devices

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, responsive-design, paging

I am working with [DataTables](https://datatables.net) which is having paging enabled and shows 'next/previous' buttons with page-numbers(1,2,3,4,5,...,10).

I am trying to change this to only 'next/previous' in smaller devices (less than 768px) using [pagingType](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType) option provided by plugin.

I have tried using responsive method but its not working:

```
responsive: {
  pagingType: "simple"
}
```

[image: output]

I can have solution using following css but I want not to generate those buttons 
 inside DOM

```
.dataTables_paginate ul.pagination .paginate_button:not(.previous):not(.next){    
  display: none;    
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dataTable").dataTable({
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    lengthChange: false,
    responsive: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    oLanguage: {
      oPaginate: {
        sNext: 'Next <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>',
        sPrevious: '<i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i> Previous'
      }
    },
    iDisplayLength: 5,
    responsive: {
      pagingType: "simple"
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card card-body card-panel mb-3">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

  <h4 class="card-title">Datatable Paging</h4>
  <table class="table" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="all">Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Method</th>
        <th class="all">Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is the code: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/eirenaios/pen/VwZWZNr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using `Window width` condition for `pagingType`.

```
pagingType: $(window).width() < 768 ? "simple" : "simple_numbers"
```

Check Snippet for the example. Please resize and refresh to view the output.

In Snippet if resolution is `more then 768` then you will see the all the `number` along with `next and previous` button.

and lower then `768` you will see only `next and previous` button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dataTable").dataTable({
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    lengthChange: false,
    responsive: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    oLanguage: {
      oPaginate: {
        sNext: 'Next <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>',
        sPrevious: '<i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i> Previous'
      }
    },
    iDisplayLength: 5,
    pagingType: $(window).width() < 768 ? "simple" : "simple_numbers"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card card-body card-panel mb-3">
  <h4 class="card-title">Datatable Paging</h4>
  <table class="table" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="all">Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Method</th>
        <th class="all">Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For Datatables+Bootstrap, use CSS  media query:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .pagination .paginate_button:not(.previous):not(.next){
        display: none;
    }
}
```

For Datatble wothout Bootstrap, use:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .dataTables_paginate span{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dataTable").dataTable({
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    lengthChange: false,
    responsive: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    oLanguage: {
      oPaginate: {
        sNext: 'Next <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>',
        sPrevious: '<i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i> Previous'
      }
    },
    iDisplayLength: 5,
    responsive: {
      pagingType: "simple"
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .pagination .paginate_button:not(.previous):not(.next) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card card-body card-panel mb-3">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

  <h4 class="card-title">Datatable Paging</h4>
  <table class="table" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="all">Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Method</th>
        <th class="all">Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no span element inside my actual paging DOM, BDW I am looking for non-css answer here! and to be specific not to generate that span to be specific. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: updated DataTable reference which uses bootstrap style now. Can you please re-check, sorry my bad.

Comment: @eirenaios so did you want an updated CSS option or no?

Comment: Guess you figured it out yourself :)

Comment: css option will work here but it is still generating those number-buttons in code, better if done using DataTable+jQuery. BDW can you please update your answer as per my new updated DOM. I will accept your answer if not find other solutions. (check my answer for the hint) thanks

Comment: Please keep your current answer and add 2nd solution for Bootstrap DOM. Both will be helpful for other users.

Comment: I updated and Ill try something different as well to see if datatables has a better option

Answer (score 1):

CSS only answer will be:

```
.dataTables_paginate ul.pagination .paginate_button:not(.previous):not(.next){
  display: none;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dataTable").dataTable({
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    lengthChange: false,
    responsive: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    oLanguage: {
      oPaginate: {
        sNext: 'Next <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>',
        sPrevious: '<i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i> Previous'
      }
    },
    iDisplayLength: 5,
    responsive: {
      pagingType: "simple"
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.dataTables_paginate ul.pagination .paginate_button:not(.previous):not(.next) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card card-body card-panel mb-3">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

  <h4 class="card-title">Datatable Paging</h4>
  <table class="table" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="all">Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Method</th>
        <th class="all">Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>M123456</td>
        <td>10/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```